# How do you put a directory list into a listbox

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a Powershell Script, which will search specified folder and list all subfolders into a listbox.  When the user selects a folder from the listbox, an action is performed.

I'm fairly new to powershell so I don't know if I'm on the right track but I've tried putting the directory into an array, I just have no idea how to get the array into the listbox.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path


foreach ($item in $items)

{

  # if the item is a directory, then process it.

  if ($item.Attributes -eq "Directory")

  {

        Write-Host $item.Name

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For demo, here's a simple form that fills a listbox with subfolder paths.

```
$rootFolder = 'PATH TO YOUR ROOTFOLDER HERE'

# get an array of subfolder full names in the $rootFolder
$subfolders = (Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Recurse -Directory).FullName

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "SubFolders"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,180)
$listBox.Anchor = 'Top,Right,Bottom,Left' 

# fill the listbox with subfolder names
$listBox.items.AddRange($subfolders)

# add an event handler on the listbox to do something with the selected item
$listBox.Add_Click({
    # here put your code to perform some action with the selected subfolder
    $selected = $listBox.GetItemText($listBox.SelectedItem)
    # for demo, simply show a messagebox
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You selected subfolder`r`n`r`n$selected", "Subfolder")
})

$form.Controls.Add($listBox) 

$form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()
```

---

**Update**

As per your comment, you would like to add a second column to the listbox where the LastWriteTime (lastModified) date is shown.

The earlier code can be adapted quite easily to add string items that are a combination of the folder FullNames, combined with the LastWriteTime using some sort of separation character. Later on, split the selected item out on that character to get the foldername only.

However, for user experience, this would make a mess of the whole thing..
Adding a new column would be nicer, but although the Listbox object does have a `MultiColumn` property, the result of using that is most likely **NOT** what you expect..

Below the updated code for using multiple columns in a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listview) object instead of a `ListBox`.

```
$rootFolder = 'PATH TO YOUR ROOTFOLDER HERE'

# get an array of subfolder objects in the $rootFolder
$subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Recurse -Directory

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "SubFolders"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,400) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$listView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$listView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$listView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(560,280) 
$listView.Anchor = 'Top,Right,Bottom,Left'
$listView.View = 'Details'
$listView.FullRowSelect = $true
$listView.GridLines = $true

[void]$listView.Columns.Add("Folder", 338);
[void]$listView.Columns.Add("LastModified", 200);
# fill the listbox with subfolder names and Last Modified dates
$subfolders | ForEach-Object {
    $row = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem( $_.FullName)  # the folder path goes into the first column
    [void]$row.SubItems.Add($_.LastWriteTime.Tostring())               # the LastWriteTime goes into the second column
    [void]$listView.Items.Add($row)
}

# add an event handler on the listbox to do something with the selected item
$listView.Add_Click({
    # here put your code to perform some action with the selected subfolder
    $selected = $listView.SelectedItems[0].Text
    # for demo, simply show a messagebox
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You selected subfolder`r`n`r`n$selected", "Subfolder")
})

$form.Controls.Add($listView) 

[void]$form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you.  I am now trying to add the Last Modified Date in a second column in the listbox.  Can you help me figure that out?  I can get it to add the date in the same column however I'm going to use selected item to call a script in the folder, so I can't have the Folder Name and Last Modified date in the selected answer, otherwise I won't be able to call the script using the selection.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @MP I have updated my code to add a second column. Hope you like it!

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly!